# Setting body classes in Zend

Tags: css, zend-framework, frameworks, styles

I am working on a Zend 1.12 application and trying to get style classes assigned to layout body tag.

I found this sample Bootstrap.php file that seems to handle the task:
https://gist.github.com/fideloper/1302688

It seems to integrate nicely, but the body's class always comes out blank.

Can someone please point me in the right direction here on how to get classes assigned to body?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a small change to the snippet I referenced above.

```
class AppName_Helper_BodyClass extends Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Container_Standalone {

    private $_classes = array();

    public function __construct($classes = null) {
        if(is_array($classes)) {
            $this->addClass($classes);
        }
    }

    public function addClass($class) {
        if(is_array($class)) {
            foreach($class as $k => $c) {
                if(is_string($c)) {
                    if(is_string($k)) {
                        $this->addClass($k.'-'.$c); //recursion
                    } else {
                        $this->addClass($c);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Zend_Exception('Class must be a string - is type: '.gettype($c));
                }
            }
            return $this;
        }

        if(is_string($class)) {
            $this->_classes[] = $class;
            return $this;
        } else {
            throw new Zend_Exception('Class must be a string - is type: '.gettype($class));
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeClass($class) {
        $key = array_search($class, $this->_classes);
        if($key !== false) {
            unset($this->_classes[$key]);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function bodyClass() {
        return $this;
    }

    public function toString() {
        return implode(' ', $this->_classes);
    }
}
```

This snippet goes into my layout:

```
$uri = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParams();
$this->bodyClass()->addClass($uri);
```

The results is such (for module - "default", controller - "auth", action - "signin"):

```
<body class="controller-auth action-signin module-default">
```

I am grabbing current request's parameters and mapping them to the body class. Hope this helps someone dealing with this.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of that helper you need to call one of it's methods to add a class. From one of your controllers:

```
$this->view->bodyClass()->addClass('something');
```

is that how you are using it?

Comment: Tim, you are right about the usage and your snippet is on point. I, however, looking for a dynamic filling of the body class depending on the current location within the app (say "module controller action"). Any idea on that?